# append on click id from button jquery

Tags: jquery

Hello friends i am trying to get the id of a button on click whith jquery and append it in the bottom of the href i try with .append but i don´t get

i have this

```html
<button class="btn1" id="5" type="button">click me</button>
<button class="btn1" id="3" type="button">click me</button>

<a href="www.example.com/{id]" class="dellink">Delete</a>
```

this works but i only need to get the id of the botton

```js
$("btn1").click(function(){
    $(".delllink").attr("href", "http://www.example.com/");
});
```

Comment: Where's the JS/jQ, friend?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way, if you want to keep the url from the element.

```js
$("button.btn1").click(function() {
    var url = $("a.dellink").attr("href");
    url = url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) + $(this).attr("id");

    $("a.dellink").attr("href", url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn1" id="5" type="button">click me</button>
<button class="btn1" id="3" type="button">click me</button>
<a href="www.example.com/{id}" class="dellink">Delete</a>
```

Otherwise you can do it more static too:

```js
$("button.btn1").click(function() {
    $("a.dellink").attr("href", "http://www.example.com/" + $(this).attr("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn1" id="5" type="button">click me</button>
<button class="btn1" id="3" type="button">click me</button>
<a href="www.example.com/{id}" class="dellink">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will work for you:

```
$('button').click(function() { 
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
   $("a").prop("href", "www.example.com/"+id);
});
```

Comment: I know it is working, but it should be `attr`, because `href` is an attribute and not a property. :)

Comment: The difference between prop and attr is that attr grabs the HTML attribute where as prop grabs the DOM property.

Comment: using prop is faster than attr because it updates the dom instead of modifying the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".btn1").click(function(){
            var href = "www.example.com/" + $(this).attr("id");
            $(".dellink").attr("href", href);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the id of **button** on **click** of it using jQuery's `attr` method, Also you can replace the `href` attribute using same `attr` method.

Documentation to `attr` is available [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Below code will solve your problem

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id'); //getting id using jQuery
    $('.dellink').attr('href', 'http://www.example.com/' + id); //changing the href attribute using jQuery.
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @LambdaNinja Thanks. added description next time will keep in mind.

Answer (score -1):

**HTMl**

```
<a href="www.example.com/" class="dellink">Delete</a>
```

**JS**

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

   // now for url either use static like this
   var p_href = "www.example.com/";

   //or do dynamic 
   var p_href = document.location.hostname+"/";
   $("a.dellink").attr("href", p_href + id);
});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/26nxLze3/2/)

Comment: But then your url would be `www.example.com/{id]5` and then `www.example.com/{id]53` and so on. ;)

Comment: @eisbehr I have posted the fiddle and removed that thing from href,,, will post that code too

Comment: @eisbehr : changed

Comment: Yes, better. And change your fiddle too. ;)